# Power Bi DAX: Total for the month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to make a total for each of the months based on the working days.

So far i have working days set as 1 if the day in the month is during Monday - Friday and 0 for Saturday and Sunday. I now need to total up the 1's and make it so that it is a single value for the month.

E.g Going the weekdays is 1 and weekend is 0, January will have 22 days on each row on the table in the data mode - January 1 = 232 January 2 = 22 etc. so i can use it to divide against my target which is set to the 1st of every month.

How can i do this??

[image: Calendar Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. i haven't tested it.

```
=GROUPBY( FILTER(table, table[Working_Day]=1) , table[Month], ["new col", SUMX( CURRENTGROUP(), table[Month_Order])])
```

filter gives working day 1's data as table,then group by performed by month, then month order has been added and returns table.

Comment: I used your formula and it came back as an error: "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value". I added in a Month Number Column just in case and it is still coming up with that error. I'm trying different columns but i don't get it.

Comment: result that u r getting is table so add it to table, u might be adding it to measure which is wrong.

Comment: No i am making a new column within my calendar table.

Comment: Have you tested out the column? please can you show me what you got and how you did the formula if you get the chance. Thank you

Comment: =SUMX(FILTER(Sheet1, AND(Sheet1[Working Day]=1, Sheet1[Month]=EARLIER([Month]))) ,Sheet1[Month Order]) try this it will return column

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you for your help! I changed the Month to Weekly Date and now it is showing the working days in the week. Using month would total all the previous years so you would need to and a Month Year column to be more specific